# Store form value in an array of strings in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

So I have a post method in my nodejs application and I want to send a form from my ejs file to an array in one of my models. In the ejs file, I have a select option for the user to enter a list of subjects. Once submitted, I cannot get the values from the select option. I tried to store it in an array but it shows undefined. I have an instructor model where it stores the subjects fields in a list of string array. I am not sure what to do. Here is what I have:

admin.js

```
router.get('/newInstructor', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('newInstructor.ejs');
});

router.post('/newInstructor', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    var lisOfSubjects = [req.body.listOfSubjects];
        console.log('Subjects -> ' + lisOfSubjects);


    var newInstructor = new Instructor ({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        officeNumber: req.body.officeNum,
        cellNumber: req.body.cellNum,
        address: {
            address1: req.body.address,
            address2: req.body.address2,
            city: req.body.city,
            state: req.body.state,
            zipCode: req.body.zip
        },
        subjects: lisOfSubjects,
        officeLocation: req.body.officeLocation
    });
    console.log(newInstructor);

});
```

ejs view file

```
<!-- js function to insert and remove from the select option-->
    <script>
                function insertTeachingSelect() {
                    var text = document.getElementById("subject").value;
                    console.log(text);

                    var select = document.getElementById("listOfSubjects");
                    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(text, 'Value1');
                }

            function removeTeachingSelect() {
                var removeSelect = document.getElementById("listOfSubjects");
                removeSelect.remove(removeSelect.selectedIndex);
            }
    </script>
......

<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-label-group">
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
 <label for="Enter subject">Enter subject</label>
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-label-group">
<input type="button" onclick="insertTeachingSelect()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Add more">
<input type="button" onclick="removeTeachingSelect()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Remove">
  </div>
   </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" id="officeLocation" name="officeLocation" class="form-control" placeholder="Office location" required="required">
                                <label for="officeLocation">Office location</label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-label-group">
                     <select id="listOfSubjects" name="listOfSubjects"size="5"></select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

                        <div class="form-group ">
                         <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                              <div class="form-label-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
```

Comment: What does `console.log(req.body.listOfSubjects);` print?

Comment: It prints out undefined

Comment: What are your select options? I do not see any options in you code here.

Comment: I have a javascript function that adds the select options when the user enters in the field for subject and clicks add

Comment: Try using F12 inside your browser to see what's actually being sent across the wire. Then reduce your example to something that works (start by hardcoding the selection values then make sure they get sent across then make them dynamic later).